# 'Which', 'whose' or something else?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, relative-clauses, possessive-of-which

I would appreciate your help phrasing the following:

> I am looking for elements
>    **which/whose/... size/sizes is/are** relatively large.

Comment: As a native speaker, I'm pretty sure I have never encountered sentences of the form "the car which door got scratched". Can you dig up any links or references where you saw this?

Comment: @Rahul: I concur with this. "Whose" is correct here.

Comment: Perhaps those who recommended "which" actually meant "of which", which is an acceptable alternative to "whose".

Comment: @Cerberus perhaps that's why people confuse them, but it's not always a drop-in replacement and sometimes requires a change in the word order.

Comment: @Cerberus: I agree. There is an old, dead superstition about using "whose" for animate objects and "of which" for inanimate objects. Merriam Webster's Dictionary of English Usage quotes an American grammarian who said, "Grammarians would perhaps differ less, if they read more." :-)

Comment: If there is a whose for who, why is there no whiches (whichse would just sound and look too weird, even for English) for which? It's rather confusing to a non-native English speaker to suddenly being confronted with a whose, which is based on who, suddenly counting for both animate and inanimate objects while who itself doesn't. Then again, English is confusing anyway ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Whose* is the way to go here. Merriam-Webster defines it [as follows](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whose):

> of or relating to whom or which especially as possessor or possessors

*Which* wouldn't work, because it doesn't indicate possession. It would work, however, if the phrase read:

> I am looking for elements which are relatively large (in size).

As to the "size is" vs "sizes are", I would say that both are grammatically correct, though the singular is preferred. The Google stats look as follows:

- "are * whose sizes are" — 94,700
- "are * whose size is" — 1,020,000

Searching the British National Corpus returns [four results](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=whose+size+is&mysubmit=Go) for "whose size is" (one of which is actually used with a plural noun, "segments whose size is"), but [none](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=whose+sizes+are&mysubmit=Go) for "whose sizes are".

Comment: I'd just go with "which are relatively large".

Answer (score 15):

Indeed, *whose* is the (only) correct possessive form, for both animate (sentient) and inanimate objects.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/whose) supports this.

> In addition, the possessive version of
>   the non-sentient pronouns is the same
>   as that of who: whose takes this role
>   for all of them. E.g., "I will have to
>   fix the car whose engine I ruined".

Comment: Posts like [this one](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/forum/showthread.php?38-Possessive-form-of-quot-which-quot&p=334#post334) (suggesting that "whose" on inanimate objects is dubious) are also responsible for seeding doubt in my mind. Thanks for clarifying this once and for all :)

Comment: Glad to help. And yeah, there is definitely some wrong information out there about the subject. (I was always taught to use *whose* in all cases, thankfully.)

Comment: @romkyns: Yes, I don't often use the word "wrong" in reference to language, but that post you referenced is plain wrong.

Comment: I'm debating (with myself, natch) if I should -1 for making Wikipedia sound authoritative.  ;-)

Answer (score 12):

The word you need is [*whose*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whose).

Answer (score 7):

Using "whose" in such cases is correct. This thread over at the Daily Writing Tips forum addresses your question: [Possessive form of "which"](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/forum/showthread.php?38-Possessive-form-of-quot-which-quot&p=334#post334).