# Other ways of saying whichs

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, possessives, animacy, possessive-of-which

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Which', 'whose' or something else?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/which-whose-or-something-else)

Of course there isn't a word whichs (as far as I know), but I am talking about the possessive form of which.

Sometimes I use 'whose', but sometimes it just seems inappropriate and that 'who' seems a bit unnatural when being used for inanimate things.

Is it only me who thinks this?

Other times I use 'the X of which', but that can seem a bit convoluted sometimes.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: "Whose" *is* the perfectly grammatical, absolutely appropriate possessive form of "which". See this question: ['Which', 'whose' or something else?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/)