# Use of "which" in a sample phrase

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Other ways of saying whichs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/other-ways-of-saying-whichs)

Is the following grammatically correct?

> Sampling was mainly random, with the exception of some services *which* indexes, calculated with the Triadas method, were not satisfactory

The indices belong to the services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  *Whose* is the word required, not *which*:

> Sampling was mainly random, with the exception of some services *whose* indexes, calculated with the Triadas method, were not satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

"Which," here, indicates that the indices were services.  "Whose" is possessive.