# Can 'whose' be used for objects?

Tags: possessives, animacy, possessive-of-which

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the word 'whose' referring to an inanimate object correct in this sentence? Is there a more appropriate word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/is-the-word-whose-referring-to-an-inanimate-object-correct-in-this-sentence-i)

Basically I'm wondering if a sentence like this is grammatically correct: "Meaning is thwarted by its delivery, whose poetry is relative to taste." I cannot avoid it with, "Meaning is thwarted by its delivery; its poetry is relative to taste" because 'its' seems to refer to 'meaning.' There needs to be a word like 'whichs' or something. Or is there?

Please clarify my question if you know the proper grammatical labels for what I'm talking about; I know them not.

Comment: This question gets asked [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9205/) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/) again, every single week, sometimes twice a day. And it's very basic, too. Please search before posting, or just look up "whose" in a dictionary of your choice to see that it is perfectly fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

There's no problem with the usage you mention: "whose" can have both inanimate or animate referents (and there's no such form "which's"). Don't get confused into thinking that "whose" is just some weird spelling of "who's": its meaning and syntax are different.

As for a grammatical label, there's no single "proper" grammatical label: it depends on the particular framework of analysis you're using. In some Chomskyan frameworks, "whose" would be referred to as a "wh-determiner". I'm not sure why that matters for your purposes or what you lose by just referring to it using the grammatical label "whose"...

Comment: The authors of the Longman grammar call it an interrogative determiner when it introduces an interrogative clause and a relative determiner when, as in the OP's example, it introduces a relative clause.

Comment: Yeah, different people will call it different spurious things. I'm still curious as to what it buys you over just calling it "whose".