# Can “whose” refer to an inanimate object?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, possessives, animacy, possessive-of-which

> We lit a fire **whose** fuel was old timber wood.

Is the word *whose* referring to *fire*, an inanimate object, correct in this sentence? Or is there a more appropriate word?

Comment: Related: ['Which', 'whose' or something else?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/which-whose-or-something-else)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The word "whose" is used in several different grammatical ways. For some of these (see my original answer below), it has been grammatical to use it for inanimate objects, at least since the days of Shakespeare. For others (see my update), it is only used for people or animals.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Many people seem to believe that you cannot use *whose* for inanimate objects, but I don't believe this was ever proscribed except by out-of-control grammarians. Consider the following quotes from Shakespeare (selected from many more quotes where *whose* refers to an inanimate object) and more recent authors:

*Hamlet* I.v

> I could a tale unfold whose lightest
>   word
>   Would harrow up thy soul, freeze
>   thy young blood,

*Two Gentlemen of Verona,* III.ii

> By wailful sonnets, whose composed rhymes
>       Should be full-fraught with serviceable vows.

*Timon of Athens* IV.iii

> The sea's a thief, whose liquid surge resolves
>       The moon into salt tears:

Jane Austen also used *whose* to refer to inanimate objects:

*Pride and Prejudice* (1813)

> On reaching the house, they were shown through the hall into the saloon, whose northern aspect rendered it delightful for summer.

Also F. Scott Fitzgerald:

*The Great Gatsby* (1925)

> I walked out the back way ... and ran for a huge black knotted tree whose massed leaves made a fabric against the rain.

Not to mention Pat Conroy:

*South of Broad* (2010)

> ... as I walk down Church Street, whose palmetto trees are rattling and whose oaks shake with the ancient grief of storm.

UPDATE: I just realized that *whose* is used in several different grammatical ways. In some of these ways, I would never use *whose* for anything but a person or animal. In particular, one of *whose*'s uses is as an interrogative pronoun, as in:

> Whose shoes are these?
>   Whose are these shoes?

If you had some leaves, and were asking which tree they fell off of, you cannot say:

> *Whose leaves are these?
>   *Whose are these leaves?

You have to say something like

> Which tree's leaves are these?

But when it is a relative pronoun that immediately follows its antecedant, *whose* can be used for inanimate objects:

> The tree whose leaves look like hands ....

This may be part of the cause of the confusion about whether *whose* can only be used for people or animals.

Comment: There’s also a common idiom, *an idea whose time has come*.

Comment: A random sample of 100 uses of *whose* from COCA included cases where it referred to *a gene*; *a crime*; *a compact*; *a concept*; *a power company*; *a now-defunct Internet company*; *an exclusive resort hotel*; *Prague*; *one cave*; *Pakistan*; *entrances*; *parotid masses*; *light-water reactors*; *f-shaped holes*; *high-speed electrons*; *a model of change*; *a major city, Chunchikmil*; *aggressive life-threatening cancers*; and *the Russian Avant-Garde Foundation*. So depending on what you consider “animate”, maybe 19% of the time *whose* refers to something inanimate.

Comment: (COCA is the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/).)

Comment: As one of those out-of-control grammarians, I like to make a distinction between "who" and "that" in sentences like "This is the knife *that* was used to kill" and "This is the person *who* is accused."  English does not have a word similar to "whose" that is used for non-humans in the way we use "that" as opposed to "who."  For OOC grammarians, like me, it would be nice to have something like "We lit a fire *thats* fuel was old timber wood," but we'll suffer through the ambiguity.

Comment: @oosterwal That marks you as not an OOC grammarian. A true OOCG would never say that it would be nice if the language had a feature that it lacks. They'd either simply say "*whose* is wrong for inanimate objects" or else go so far as to say "the correct word is *thats* and has been for everyone who speaks English properly since the dawn of time" even though they had zero evidence to back it up.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: not only that, they also delete answers claiming otherwise.

Comment: Shakespeare serves not as a guide to modern usage, but full four hundreds of years ago he wrote.

Comment: @Bob: ... And I cited Jane Austen as a more recent example to show that *whose* could still be used for inanimate objects in 1800. Do I need to cite more recent works? That's really, really easy. Just added F. Scott Fitzgerald. Do you want a 21st century writer? Got one of those, too.

Comment: 'Out-of-control grammarians' ... 'require stricter sentences'?

Answer (score 36):

English *whose* is somewhat like Latin *cuius* or Spanish *cuyo* in that it is strictly a function word.  It is just fine for anything at all.  You cannot use *which* there.

However, it does make a difference whether you use *whose* as a relative pronoun or as an interrogative pronoun.  This one is ok:

- These are the fires whose fuel needs replenishing.

But this question:

- Whose fires need replenishing?

is soliciting an answer of a person, not of a fire.  To get the other answer, you have to say:

- Which fires’ fuel needs replenishing?

You cannot say:

- Whose fires’ fuels are running low?

And get back a list of fires instead of a list of persons.

Comment: In fact we were taught in school where I was studying English that whose only restricted to inanimates...

Comment: Can I use which it there was singular number, e.g. in "the chair, which material..."?

Comment: You were taught incorrectly. You cannot use *which* in either place even when it's singular. You could say *"the chair, of which the material ..."*

Comment: It's not that he was taught incorrectly (his post Q. being ok), he's just reversed things in the comment above. He meant *animate*, is what I think.

Comment: @Kris, indeed. Just a typo.

Answer (score 7):

"Whose" is also used to refer to a component of something inanimate and your original is perfectly grammatical. I wonder if you're inventing a problem where there isn't one. If you think using "whose" sounds a bit too formal, you could say e.g. "A camera with wires going through the wall", which would maybe be what people would say in everyday spontaneous speech. It's not clear to me that "a camera of which the wires..." is more common or natural than "a camera whose wires...".

As far as grammatical category is concerned, it really depends on your model and, depending on your model, exactly what type of analysis you're doing. As a fairly broad label, it's probably fair to group it with other "wh-words" ("when", "which" etc.).

Comment: You're right, of course. [Here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=camera+whose&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) are several thousand camera whose references in writing, the vast majority of which are the same **possessive pronoun** usage as OP's example.

Answer (score 6):

[Wiktionary lists such usage as "formerly proscribed"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whose).  Presumably this means some would still proscribe it, and others consider it correct.

Personally I have no problem with it, though I would probably say the following:

> We lit a fire for which the fuel was old timber wood.

Or, better yet:

> We lit a fire, using old timber wood for fuel.

Comment: Wiktionary no longer says anything about this usage being "formerly proscribed".

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, it is done. And it is acceptable for informal writing. You may even see it in some newspapers.

For formal writing, however, *of which* should be used, because *whose* is the possessive of *who*, and *who* does not refer to an inanimate object.

Comment: +1. Without reordering the sentence, this is the truest non-living counterpart of "whose", workable into any context.

Comment: 'A reaction whose half-life changes when the reactant concentration is changed is a ...' [[Libre Texts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_for_the_Biosciences_(Chang)/09%3A_Chemical_Kinetics/9.E%3A_Chemical_Kinetics_(Exercises))] Plus many formal examples of "a ruling whose"; ' "a situation whose" +parliament'. Even some of "a crime whose" [+ cause, form, definition ...] The usage is found across all registers.