# Is the use of "whence" and "wherefrom" dated?

Tags: word-usage

I rarely see these words ("whence" and "wherefrom") written and I can't remember hearing them anywhere.

Anyhow, I find them to be a good replacement for "whose", which people use even for animals and inanimate objects, like in the sentence that follows:

> My father had a Dodge Dart, whose tires were constantly flattened by
>   the Loyd's kids when he was not home.

But I don't know if it is appropriate to write these in this context or if they're even current usages. 
The word "whose" seems more appropriate to use when talking about people.

Comment: *Whence* and *wherefrom* don't work well as direct replacements for *whose* in the quote you presented.

Comment: 1) *Whose* is the genitive of both *who* and *which*. 2) *Whence* and *wherefrom* are indeed rather dated; but in any case neither can be substituted for *whose*.

Comment: Yes, they are dated, and no, they are not appropriate in that context.

Comment: @StoneyB  Nothing wrong with being dated - in fact I'm getting a bit dated myself.

Comment: I agree that "whose" can sound a bit funny, but as others have said, you can't really use either of those words you suggested in your example sentence.

Comment: Yes, it appears *whose* is the right word.

But in utilizing the good opportunity I'd like to ask if there are any other words I can use in this context.

Comment: Just FYI, if you used "whence", the sentence would basically be: *My father had a Dodge Dart, from where (its) tires were constantly flattened...*

Comment: @DogLover, in the end, is it even right to say *(...) **from where tires** tires where constantly flattened*.
The sentence looks rather strange if written like this.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa No, it is not right. It doesn't make sense. If you really had to reword it, you could potentially say: *My father had a Dodge Dart, of which its tires...* But even then it sounds a bit awkward.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [Can 'whose' refer to an inanimate object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/can-whose-refer-to-an-inanimate-object); this thread answers the salient question. // Collins labels _wherefrom_ 'archaic' and _whence_ 'literary , or old-fashioned'. General reference.

Comment: No, whence and wherefrom 
 can't substitute for whose there; what makes you think they could?

Comment: If you don’t like *whose* try: My father had a Dodge Dart. Its tires were constantly flattened by the Loyd's kids when he was not home.

Comment: I think you were thinking of "whereof" - "a Dodge Dart whereof the tires were constantly flattened" or "a Dodge Dart the tires whereof were constantly flattened".  But it sounds stilted.  You'd be better off sticking with "whose" and confronting the myth that it can't be used of inanimates.

Comment: *Whence* and *wherefrom* are both dated but thereafter you seem to have lost touch with reality.

Please first explain how you could imagine either of them replacing *whose*?

This has nothing to do with *current usage*. It’s simply wrong.

Please explain how you think *whence* and *whose* could be related, let alone *a good replacement* either way.

Answer (score -2):

Yes those words are dated but in the correct context still work. What you're doing though is most certainly misusing them as neither can replace whose.

Comment: Collins labels _wherefrom_ 'archaic', which means that the correct context would be very rare.

Comment: Charlotte, could you explain in enough detail that the OQ might grasp it, please?