# What is the appropriate usage of this Who's and What's to imply possession of a property

Tags: possessives

Consider the following sentences:

> 1. Please consider the person who's shirt is red.
> 2. Please consider the car what's bumper is blue.
> 3. Please consider the car who's bumper is blue.

Number 3 sounds wrong to me and number 1 sounds right.  A car cannot be a "who" unless its a work of fiction. The question here is whether or not number 2 is correct form.

Is number 2 correct form? Why or why not? If not, what would be the correct form to refer to a specific inanimate object what's component is blue or based on some other criteria.  What rule specifies that it is correct or not correct.

Comment: They're all wrong. You should be using "whose" which is the possesive form of "who" and "that's" instead of "what's".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can “whose” refer to an inanimate object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/can-whose-refer-to-an-inanimate-object). But << whose vs who's >> is a basic question possibly acceptable on ELL. The only possessive usage involving _Who's_ I can think of would be if you dropped the _Dr_ from _Dr Who's canine friend._ Otherwise, _who's_ means _who is_ or _who has_.

Comment: @KillingTime No, *that's* is wrong there. *What's* is definitely non-standard, but certainly not unknown; a more standard way would be to use *whose*.

Comment: A more idiomatic phrasing could be: "Please consider the person in the red shirt" and "Please consider the car with the blue bumper."