# Possessive "that's"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, relative-clauses, animacy, possessive-of-which

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Which', 'whose' or something else?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/which-whose-or-something-else)

Is the use of "that's" correct in the sentence below?

> Imagine a frame with two sets of strings stretched across, making a grid that's intersections define a curve.