# Can't figure out how to say this sentence

Tags: sentence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [possessive connecting word for inanimate object](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/possessive-connecting-word-for-inanimate-object)

Can't figure out how to build this sentence.

Say I have a form someone needs to fill out and one of the cells that he needs to fill (called TABLE) is the name of a table (in a database).

When he gives me the form back I'll give him another form called, say F1, containing information related to all changes made to the table specified in the TABLE cell.

If he asks me "what is the TABLE cell for?", is it possible to explain it on one sentence?

The closest I've got so far is:

> The table to which changes made the returned F1 will refer to.

Does it make sense? Should it be:

> The table to whose changes made the returned F1 will refer to .

OR

> The table to which's changes made the returned F1 will refer to.

English is not my first language so I'm unsure.

Comment: "The table whose changes the returned F1 will refer to", or "The table changes to whom the returned F1 will refer to".

Comment: That being said, in its current wording your question is a dupe of those simchona has linked to.

Answer (score 3):

You almost answered your own question in the third sentence of your question:

> When he gives me the form back I'll give him another form called, say
>   F1, containing information related to all changes made to the table
>   specified in the TABLE cell.

So:

> The TABLE cell specifies the name of the table for which you want change
>   information returned in form F1.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have the gist of what you want. 
Try:
"Cell F1 contains the changes referred to in TABLE"

Answer (score 1):

I like: "The TABLE cell selects the table whose changes will be returned in form F1."
You can also say "... selects which table's changes will ..."