# "the board of directors I have just became a member of" or "of which I have just became a member"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-order, possessives

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)
>   [Possessive connecting word for inanimate object](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/possessive-connecting-word-for-inanimate-object)

I am not sure about following sentence being grammatically correct:

> ..such as the X fund the board of directors of which I have just
>   became a member.

OR

> such as the X fund whose board of directors I have just became a
>   member (of?).

Comment: Change "became" to "become" and add "of" at the end of the first, then both are grammatical, but the second one (again, *with* the "of" at the end) is better style and more natural as well (and makes do with just two "of"s rather than three).

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both are pretty much correct, although could use a comma after fund, but neither are very readable. It would be easier to say "whose board of directors I have joined"