# Analysis's output vs analysis output vs output of the analysis

Tags: possessives, possessive-s-vs-of

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apostrophe “s” vs “Of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/apostrophe-s-vs-of)
>   [possessive connecting word for inanimate object](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/possessive-connecting-word-for-inanimate-object)

Once again I'm not sure if I should use possessive or atributive or neither of them.

> 1. Please, send me an e-mail with the analysis's output.
> 2. Please, send me an e-mail with the analysis output.
> 3. Please, send me an e-mail with the output of the analysis.

Which one of them is the most idiomatic?
There is any rule or recommendation about when one must use possessive/attributive or the one mentioned 
above in example 3.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is using the possessive 's correct in “the car's antenna”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1031/2085)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "*Please send me an e-mail with the analysis.*"

The "output" isn't necessary.

Comment: True in this case, but not addressing the actual question.