# Is it correct to say "research competitor products" or "research competitors' products"?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Is it correct to say: "We research **competitor** products or "We research **competitors'** products"? In general, should a singular or plural noun be used in such cases?

I tried looking for an answer online, but found conflicting information. Hoping to get some clarity on this thread.

Thanks!

Comment: What was the conflicting information you found online?

Comment: Is there more than one competitor whose products you study ?

Comment: Either could work, depending on what you are trying to say. Are the products themselves doing the competing with your products, or are other companies competing with your company?

Comment: I wouldn't use either. It's [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+competitor+products%2Cof+competitor%27s+products%2Cof+competing+products%2Cof+competitive+products&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) to refer to ***competing products***. Or as @Graffito suggests, ***competitive products***, but that may carry a slightly different nuance - products which are potentially as good as the contextually relevant product(s), as opposed to products offered by other companies in competition with the contextually relevant company.

Comment: This has been asked a lot - [see this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun-the-dell-companys-staff-or-the-dell-company-st) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/analysiss-output-vs-analysis-output-vs-output-of-the-analysis) but the chain of duplicates doesn't really go to an answer I can see.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well its "OK" that you wouldn't use either (even after editing your comment to alleviate some of the oversimplification); however, that implies that you never had or assume you never will have to communicate that you are researching on competitors' products. Because if you suggest to use "competing products" instead you never were and never will never be able to convey that meaning. To speak of a "nuance" in that context is very interesting (wrong :)

Comment: @SebastianE: My postulated nuance of difference between *competing* and *competitive* products would rarely be significant, even if everyone agreed what that distinction actually was. But surely you've only got to compare relative prevalence of all 4 forms in my linked usage chart to see that neither of *competitor / competitors'* products is used much. If people need to ask here (which should be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) anyway), they probably shouldn't choose ridiculously uncommon phrasing on the off chance it might more accurately reflect what they mean.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, it's good that we agree on the significant difference between competitors' products and competing products (or competitive products, which is actually even worse because "good design makes a competitive product"). I think a quick google scholar search can help to contextualize "ridiculously unommon phrasing".

Answer (score 2):

There is a **significant** difference in meaning between ***competing products*** (which was suggested in the comments a supposedly superior, since more "popular", alternative) and ***competitors' products*** in the context of doing research.

If you research ***competing products*** you're looking for products that compete with your own products, i.e., you are not looking at competitors' products which are not competing with your own products.

If you research ***competitors' products***, then you are looking at products of a competitor, whose competing with you on any level, even if they may not directly compete with your own products.

If you do research on ***competitor products*** it could mean both actually, the products of a competitor or the products that are competitors to your products.

Here is a nice example for competitors' products

> "Firms have an incentive to test competitors’ products to reveal
> violations of safety and environmental standards, in order to have
> competitors’ products blocked from sale."

from Erica L. Plambeck, Terry A. Taylor (2018) Testing by Competitors in Enforcement of Product Standards. Management Science 65(4):1735-1751.

While the question is certainly "improvable", one can find something to answer in it, which is actually trivial, but the discussion in the comments shows that it maybe is not.