# Using "whose" with non-animate nouns

Tags: grammaticality, animacy, possessive-of-which

> **Duplicate:**
>   [Is the word 'whose' referring to an inanimate object correct in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/is-the-word-whose-referring-to-an-inanimate-object-correct-in-this-sentence-i)
>   [Possessive connecting word for inanimate object](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/possessive-connecting-word-for-inanimate-object)
>   [Usage of “whose” not referring to a person.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21078/usage-of-whose-not-referring-to-a-person) 
>   [Referring to some attribute of an inanimate object — use “who's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/referring-to-some-attribute-of-an-inanimate-object-use-whos)
>   [What is the possessive form of “what”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9205/what-is-the-possessive-form-of-what)
>   [Other ways of saying “whichs”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/other-ways-of-saying-whichs)
>   [Possessive “that's”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25300/possessive-thats)
>   ['Which', 'whose' or something else?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/which-whose-or-something-else)

Let us consider the following sentence:

> Japanese language uses ideograms *whose* Chinese origin is not disputed.

Is it correct to use *whose* in relation to ideograms or should I use *which* better?